# User ID with PHP session

Tags: php, mysql, session

How can I save the user Id when is filling a form using PHP (Sessions)?? I mean how do get this session and I write the SQL query to save the uder ID in the form that has been submitted...

This is my session

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $data['user_id'];
$_SESSION['first_name'] = $data['first_name'];
```

and here when the user log in to fill the form

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['agent']) OR ($_SESSION['agent'] != md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) )) {
    // Need the functions:
    require ('includes/login_functions.inc.php');
    redirect_user();
    // Print a message:
}
echo "<span>You are now logged in, {$_SESSION['first_name']}!<a href=\"logout.php\">Logout</a></p></span>";
```

Comment: can you please little bit format you question and add detail also what is issue and what you want?

Comment: Sorry this is a bit messy ... It is my first time making a question here.
I create this session
 session_start();
$_SESSION['id'] = $data['id'];
$_SESSION['first_name'] = $data['first_name'];

And the user login and fill the request form... 
When the user submit the form I want to save its ID, so only that user can be editing that request.

Comment: @Lucelli What do you mean by *I want to save its ID* when you already have the *id* in `$_SESSION['id']`?

Comment: As a note, MD5 is completely worthless even for things like this. What are you trying to do? Detect when the user-agent has changed? Sometimes that happens if you re-size the browser window. Pinning it like that can be super annoying for some users.

Comment: Okay how do I pass that $_SESSION['id'] and save in databases?

Comment: You need to save the `user_id` value beforehand. Keep in mind session management and login security in general is actually a deceptively complicated, hard problem to solve properly. Most [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in, so there's really no need to painfully re-invent the wheel here.

Comment: I spent some time looking at authentication system that Laravel has and it looks easier to use it other than trying to code my own one. But I have few  pages already created, like almost my entire application done, except the user authentication. 
Is it possible have just have part of my application using Laravel and put together with the rest of my application, or should I start everything from 0??